# creating a new column in data frame conditoned on values of a previous column using a loop

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

Lets say I have a data frame that has three columns named "SNP" (unique IDs), "A1" and "P".

```
SNP | A1 | P
rs12  A    0.3426
rs16  B    0.0083
rs18  B    0.0046
```

I am trying to create new column in the data named "A2" based on if column "A1" has an A then R will put a B in column "A2" and if column "A1" has a B to put an A in column "A2"

This is what I have, I'm not sure if I'm tackling this the right way but here's a try.

```
data<-(read data in)
allele<-function(x) {
    isOkay<-all(data[data$A2=="A"])
    flag<- ifelse(isOkay, A, B)
      return(flag)
}

data <- split(data, data$SNP)
A2 <- sapply(data, allele)
```

Comment: No need for a loop.  You can do this with vectors.  Look at `ifelse` or `switch`.

Comment: I think you need to describe your data better. Is it several rows per SNP? If so, can one SNP have both A and B? Can A1 only take values A and B?

Comment: @AriB.Friedman - I'm not sure how useful `switch` would be here, as it is non-vectorised it would be need to be wrapped in `sapply` or something similar.

Comment: I tried using match and it worked

Comment: @Henrik I think I was making it harder than it seems but the match seems to work data$A2 <- c("A","B")[
match(data$A1, c("B", "A"),
nomatch=2 )]

Comment: @AriB.Friedman I tried using data$A2[data$A1=="A"]<-"B",ifelse(data$A2{data$A1=="B"]<-"A")
but it didn't work

Comment: @thelatemail I agree but easy enough to wrap it and if there are more than 2 values than it works better than `ifelse`.

Comment: @geneteics_diva, OK when I read the text the problem felt very `ifelse`-ish, but when I looked at your script and saw `all`, `split` by SNP et c, I got slightly confused.

Answer (score 0):

**#assuming your column A1 takes only two values A and B and your data is mydata**

```
mydata$A2<-with(mydata,ifelse(A1=="A","B","A")) 
> mydata
   SNP A1      p A2
1 rs12  A 0.3426  B
2 rs16  B 0.0083  A
3 rs18  B 0.0046  A
```

Comment: thank you, I definitely made this more difficult than it seems. I was also able to use match which did the same thing 
data$A2 <- c("A","B")[
match(data$A1, c("B", "A"),
nomatch=2 ) @Metrics